# Get the Sum of Unique IDs from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I need to loop through an array of objects and sum the total number of *unique* _id(s). Imagine a data structure that looks like this:

```
  [
      { firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Johnson",
        _id: 23
      },
      { firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Johnson",
        _id: 23
      },
      { firstName: "Mary",
        lastName: "Smith",
        _id: 24
      }
  ]
```

... for the above data set, my `totalUniqueIDs` should be `2`.

If I were just looping through an array and getting the sum of "_id", I would do this:

```
let customersArray = docs.map(doc => doc._id);
let customersArrayLength = customersArray.length
console.log(customersArrayLength); // 3
```

This would of course give me 3 results.

How would I get just the sum of *unique* _id(s) in this situation? Do I first convert the `array` to a `set`, and then find the `length` or `size`?

Comment: I think you've got the right idea. I'd add all the ID's to a set and then sum up the values within the set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is using `reduce` to summarise the array into an object using the _id as the key. Use `Object.values` to convert back the object into an array.

```js
var arr = [{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Johnson","_id":23},{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Johnson","_id":23},{"firstName":"Mary","lastName":"Smith","_id":24}]

var result = Object.values(arr.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {[v._id]:v}), {}));

console.log(result.length);
```

---

Another option is using `new Set` and `size` property

```js
var arr = [{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Johnson","_id":23},{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Johnson","_id":23},{"firstName":"Mary","lastName":"Smith","_id":24}]

var result = new Set(arr.map(o => o._id)).size;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `.map()` to get an array of `ids` and use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to dedupe it :

```js
const data = [{
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    _id: 23
  },
  {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    _id: 23
  },
  {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Smith",
    _id: 24
  }
]

const result = [... new Set(data.map(({_id}) => _id))]

console.log(result.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all the `_id` from your array of object using  [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to find unique `_id` and finally use `size` to get how many of ids are unique?

1. The **Set** object lets you store unique values of any type
2. The **map()** method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array

```js
var obj = [{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Johnson",
    "_id": 23
  },
  {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Johnson",
    "_id": 23
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Mary",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "_id": 24
  }
];

function countUnique(iterable) {
  return new Set(iterable).size;
}

finalArray = obj.map(function(obj) {
  return obj._id;
});

console.log(countUnique(finalArray));
```